# eclipse on Ubuntu 17.10 - toolbar drop down menus and pop ups moved when using dual monitor set up

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, java, 17.10, eclipse

When I use eclipse oxygen on Ubuntu 17.10 with a dual monitor set up, the drop down menus and the pop ups from the toolbar are moved downwards:

eclipse - drop down menu:
[image: eclipse - drop down menu]

eclipse - pop up:
[image: eclipse - pop up]

Additionally, on start up, the eclipse oxygen icon is not displayed centered, but on the upper left corner (this however happens independent on the number of monitors used):

eclipse - start up icon:
[image: eclipse - start up icon]

I already tried reinstalling eclipse a couple of times. I also deleted the .eclipse folder and the eclipse workspace before reinstalling.

EDIT:

Apparently the problem with the drop down menu can be bypassed, if one aligns the two displays at the top, rather then the bottom:

drop down menu moved:
[image: drop down menu moved]

drop down menu correct:
[image: drop down menu correct]

Is there a way to align the two displays at the bottom and still have drop down menu (and pop ups) at the correct position?

The start up icon is still in the upper left corner and seems not to be affected by the display alignment.

Comment: Did you use an extractable or installable package?
I had issues with an installed Eclipse CDT, which were not present with an extracted Eclipse of the same version.